# Magnetic dipole moment due to folded loop

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, magnetic-moment

> A steady current i flows in a small square loop of wire of side L in a horizontal plane. The loop is now folded about its middle such that half of it lies in a vertical plane. Let
> $
> μ_1
> $
> and
> $
> μ_2
> $
> respectively denote the magnetic moments due to the current loop before and after folding. Then find the relation between $
> μ_1
> $
> and
> $
> μ_2
> $

This is a problem from my test.

**When the loop is folded we have two open loops. So shouldn't the net moment (after folding) be zero?**
But the solution given takes the net dipole moment as the vector sum of the individual dipole moments due to the open loops. Is this solution correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to Physics Stack Exchange. That's a very good question, and the answer illustrates an important feature of electromagnetism, superposition, which follows fom the linearity of Maxwell's equations. We can conceptually add an extra two wires along the line of the fold which complete the two loops. However the currents in the two wires are in *opposite directions* along the same line, so their magnetic fields add up to zero. That's the first superposition. Now we have two current loops, and the field is the sum of the two: that's the second superposition. So yes the given solution is correct!

Comment: So we can add the two wires because their net effect to the magnetic field is zero so it can be considered as equivalent to two loops to calculate the dipole moment Thanks:)